# Google Glass GDK: menuItem setActionView not respected in onCreateOptionsMenu (doesn't update view)

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I'm attempting to grab a `menuItem` when `onCreateOptionsMenu` is called and override the default view by using `setActionView` (I'm aware I could use `CardScrollView` and `CardScrollAdapter` but this is a lot of work just get a menu up and running).

`menu.xml`:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/test_item"
        android:title="Test 1">
```

I'll attempt to override this programmatically in `onCreateOptionsMenu`:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    View testView = new CardBuilder(this, CardBuilder.Layout.TEXT)
            .setText("Test 2.")
            .getView();

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.test_item);

    item.setActionView(testView);

    return true;
}
```

However, when I view this options menu through the glass, Test 1 still shows. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there any reason you aren't using the usual way to make a menu?

Comment: What's the usual way?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the menu title dynamically, you can override onPrepareOptionsMenu.

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.test_item);
    // may be if case to check the condition
    // String title = titleShouldBe1 ? "Test 1" : "Test 2";
    // item.setTitle(title);
    item.setTitle("Test 2");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I actually wanted to override the card's layout to another layout. Hence why I wanted to change the card's view.